why do prefixes in an array have no effect?
solving a problem in leetcode, I needed to create a matrix and take data from another matrix,
for this I wrote res[0][0]=s[0][0], but for some reason Python assigned all res[0-2][0] values ​​to s[0][0]
s= [[-2,-3,3],[-5,-10,1],[10,30,-5]]
res=[[0]*len(s)]*len(s[0])
res[0][0]=s[0][0]
print(res)

output: [[-2, 0, 0], [-2, 0, 0], [-2, 0, 0]]
but i want [[-2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
s= [[-2,-3,3],[-5,-10,1],[10,30,-5]]
res=[[0]*len(s)]*len(s[0])
res[1][0]=s[0][0]
print(res)

output: [[-2, 0, 0], [-2, 0, 0], [-2, 0, 0]]

Try: res = [[0]*len(s[0]) for _ in range(len(s))]

why does it work like that? and how is it different from mine?

res = [[0]*len(s)]*len(s[0]) creates a list where each row is a reference to the same list [0]*len(s). When you modify a row, you're modifying all the rows that reference the same list. See here.
